# Having problems with Xamarin Media Manager and Static Instantiation

Tags: c#, oop, xamarin

I want to use Xamarin MediaManager for a Web-TV project. To enable full-screen, I open a new page for this purpose. However, when I turn back to MainPage, the media player object gets disposed.

To prevent the disposal, I want to instantiate the object in every appear of the screen. However, in the source code of the MediaManager plug-in, one of the methods is defined as static. Therefore, I have some problems doing my purpose.

I am new at C#, I am trying to understand the OOP logic.

```
using System;
using Plugin.MediaManager;
using Plugin.MediaManager.Abstractions.Enums;
using Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace VideoPlayerApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        CrossMediaManager Video;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Video = new CrossMediaManager();
        }


        private async void PlayStop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PlayPauseButton.Text == "Play")
            {
                await Video.Current.Play(VideoEntry.Text, MediaFileType.Video);

                PlayPauseButton.Text = "Stop";
            }

            else if (PlayPauseButton.Text == "Stop")
            {
                await Video.Current.Pause();

                PlayPauseButton.Text = "Play";
            }
        }

        private async void FullScreen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FullScreen());
        }

    }
}
```

In the code above, the problem is in the lines:

```
await Video.Current.Play(VideoEntry.Text, MediaFileType.Video);
```

And:

```
await Video.Current.Pause();
```

The error I get is:

> Error CS0176  Member 'CrossMediaManager.Current' cannot be accessed
>   with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Thank you very much for any help&advice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to new up an instance of `CrossMediaManager`. Instead use this:

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(VideoEntry.Text, MediaFileType.Video);
```

And:

```
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
```

See more example code [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/).

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I was using the codes you mentioned. There is a problem when I use your code for an Android API 22 phone. When I go another page for fullscreen then I turn back, the player stops working and I get an exception which says that the SurfaceView object is disposed. Therefore I need to instantiate the player onAppear in my opinion. The same issue can be seen in the link : https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/170

Comment: Well it's not about opinion I'm afraid, the error message you get tells you that you need to use the type name and not the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. I found a solution for my issue. My main issue was having a disposed media manager object after coming from another page to main page. It was my mistake to have that situation. There is no need to instantiate the media manager again. Instead, do it like ;

On MainPage:

```
private async void FullScreen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FullScreen());
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
        }
```

Pause the player on the main page after navigating to other page. Then, when you come back, the player continues to play.

This solved my object disposal issue.